# Changing periodicity of time series using xts

Tags: r, xts

I have a time series with tick frequency that look like the following:

```
                        V2     V3
2004-02-01 20:20:41 1.2474 1.2484
2004-02-01 21:13:52 1.2471 1.2481
2004-02-01 21:14:09 1.2469 1.2479
2004-02-01 21:38:57 1.2470 1.2480
2004-02-01 21:56:43 1.2468 1.2478
2004-02-01 21:56:47 1.2466 1.2476
```

In order to convert it to daily frequency, I use the following codes:

```
V.xts <- xts(V[, 2:3], order.by=as.POSIXct(V[, 1], format='%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S'))
V.day<-to.daily(V.xts,OHLC=FALSE)
```

This results in the following time series with new frequency:

```
               V2     V3
2004-02-01 1.2475 1.2485
2004-02-02 1.2430 1.2432
2004-02-03 1.2544 1.2546
2004-02-04 1.2537 1.2539
2004-02-05 1.2563 1.2565
2004-02-06 1.2696 1.2706
2004-02-08 1.2642 1.2652
2004-02-09 1.2690 1.2692
2004-02-10 1.2682 1.2684
2004-02-11 1.2827 1.2829
```

in which, I guess that my codes return the close price for the daily period and there is no price for the date "2004-02-07". However, if there is no price for date "2004-02-07", I would like to record the value of the previous period in replacement of the missing value. I then use:

```
V.a <- align.time(V.day)
tmp <- xts(, seq.POSIXt(start(V.a), end(V.a), by='days'))
output <- cbind(tmp, V.a)
```

However, I got this error after the second command:

```
Error in seq.POSIXt(start(V1.a), end(V1.a), by = "days") : 
  'from' must be a "POSIXt" object
```

I install 'xts' package with dependencies : 'zoo' and 'date'.
I then tried using `seq` with the following commands:

```
tmp <- xts(, seq(start(V.a), end(V.a), by='days'))
output <- merge(tmp, V.a, fill=na.locf)
```

The new dataset that I got looks like :

```
2004-02-01     NA     NA
2004-02-01 1.2475 1.2485
2004-02-02 1.2475 1.2485
2004-02-02 1.2430 1.2432
2004-02-03 1.2430 1.2432
2004-02-03 1.2544 1.2546
2004-02-04 1.2544 1.2546
2004-02-04 1.2537 1.2539
2004-02-05 1.2537 1.2539
2004-02-05 1.2563 1.2565
2004-02-06 1.2563 1.2565
2004-02-06 1.2696 1.2706
2004-02-07 1.2696 1.2706
2004-02-08 1.2696 1.2706
2004-02-08 1.2642 1.2652
```

It seems that those commands gave me opening and closing price for each day in which opening price is closing price of the previous day. However, on date `2004-02-07`, there is only price recorded which is the closing price of the previous day. This price will still be missed if I use

```
Y.data<-as.data.frame(output)
y<-Y.data$V2
y1<-y[seq(2,length(y),2)]
```

to extract all the closing price.

Comment: Looks you have a `Date` index

Comment: Have you tried wrapping `as.POSIXct(start(V.a))`

Comment: Thanks @akrun, it works and return the first row `2004-02-01 13:00:00     NA     NA`. I wonder if there is a way to remove this row and why all the time is set at `13:01:00`?

Comment: Check your `format` string, it has slashes instead of `-`.

Answer (score 2):

You should not call methods directly for reasons like this. Your code will work fine if you just call the generic `seq` and let it do method dispatch.

You can also use `merge` and its `fill` argument to replace the `NA` with the previous value using `na.locf`.

And you do not need to call `align.time`. I'm not sure why you think you need to, but it's likely to only cause problems on daily data.

```
tmp <- xts(, seq(start(V.day), end(V.day), by='days'))
output <- merge(tmp, V.day, fill=na.locf)
```

Comment: I guess this gives me the opening and closing price of each day in which the opening price is the closing price of the previous day

Comment: Please edit that into your question. It's difficult to read as a comment. And it will be a lot easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/271616).